# HTML CSS: Fixed Element, Adjust height to TOP

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV in fixed position on bottom of page.

Problem: if Elements in this Div Box are Wrapped (responsive), the div box is growing its height to bottom, so Im not able to see the other elements.

Hence, I try to adjust the height of the div Element according to "TOP".

```
  EG: [+++++++++++++++++++++++++++]     <- WideScreen  [Elements]
        ----------------------------------

Problem:  [+++++++++            //Small Screen: Wrapping [Elements]
         ---------------      <- Window ends here
          +++++++++           <- not visible anymore
          +++++++++      ]    
    
    How its should be:
         [+++++++++
          +++++++++
          +++++++++  ]
         ----------------     //Div adjust height to TOP
```

How isit possible?

Edit:

```
    <div class="row d-inline-flex" id="bT_dragSystem" style="position: fixed;width: 100vw;z-index: 1;margin: 0;margin-top: calc(100vh - 245px);background: rgba(51,0,255,0.17);padding: 5px;padding-left: 10px;margin-left: -10px;">
        <div class="col" id="bT_dragSection" style="padding: 0;">
            <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center align-self-center flex-wrap" id="drag_formElements" style="padding: 0;height: 100%;">
               <li> Elements
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: You should add your code for more clarification.

Comment: Yes, please add your HTML and CSS that you have tried and we can assist you better her.

Comment: sure, hope its now ok

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `margin-top: calc(100vh - 245px);` (erase it), but only `bottom: 0` for a footer-type fixed element like this. You *can*  use `height: 245px` if you want (apparently that's the height you wanted), but you don't have to. If not, the height will depend on the contents and padding settings of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, already found my answer :D

```
position: fixed; overflow: hidden; bottom: 0;
```